# How to determine which View was clicked in a ListView with custom layout

Tags: android, android-view

I have a custom `ListView` which has a custom layout with a couple of views.
Can I check in the method `onItemClick()` which of these views was clicked?
I searched and found one explanation but it couldn't help me a lot.

Here is the custom view:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mHolder;
    if(convertView != null){
        mHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }else{
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_video_item,null);
        mHolder.mVideoThumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_thumbnail);
        mHolder.mVideoTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
        mHolder.mVideoFavorite = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_favorite);
        convertView.setTag(mHolder);
    }
    //Setting the data
    SearchResult result = mVideoList.get(position);
    mHolder.mVideoTitle.setText(result.getSnippet().getTitle());

    //Loading the image
    Picasso.with(mActivity).load(result.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl()).into(mHolder.mVideoThumbnail);

    return  convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    private TextView mVideoTitle = null;
    private ImageView mVideoThumbnail = null;

    //Testing
    private ImageView mVideoFavorite = null;
}
```

I need to know if the `mVideoFavorite` was clicked in this method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    SearchResult result = (SearchResult)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    VIDEO_ID = result.getId().getVideoId();
    Intent videoIntent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, AppConstants.KEY, VIDEO_ID);
    startActivity(videoIntent);
}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You would have to set a click listener in your getView method for your mVideoFavorite

Comment: @freddieptf I added onClickListener in the onItemClick method

Comment: @freddieptf Thank you very much! I did it now and it works! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you have to do is, make that imageview to capture onClick events by set its xml value :

```
android:clickable="true"
```

After you set that in your custom layout for the imageView called "mVideoFavorite", you must implement its onClick method as follow inside your getView method for custom adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder mHolder;
if(convertView != null){
    mHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}else{
    mHolder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_video_item,null);
    mHolder.mVideoThumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_thumbnail);
    mHolder.mVideoTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
    mHolder.mVideoFavorite = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_favorite);
    mHolder.mVideoFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // do your stuff
        }
    });
    convertView.setTag(mHolder);
}
//Setting the data
SearchResult result = mVideoList.get(position);
mHolder.mVideoTitle.setText(result.getSnippet().getTitle());

//Loading the image
Picasso.with(mActivity).load(result.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl()).into(mHolder.mVideoThumbnail);

return  convertView;
}
```

Basically this is what you have to at all.
Regards,

Answer (score -1):

It's nice if you posted custom listview code.

Comment: is this an answer at all?

Comment: you should've posted this as a comment to a question, not as an answer